# Making synchronous Ajax calls from a loop via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got the loop below in my code and each iteration calls a function in which there's an Ajax call.

I'm trying to find a way to make each iteration run only after the former iteration completed.

Until now, as you can see, I've used a delay as a **temporary** solution.

Is there a neat way to make it synchronized?

Thanks!

```
$.each(matchIds, function(key,val){
        setTimeout(function(){
            gettingEvents(key, val,userID);
        },delay);
        delay+=1700;

    });
```

Comment: What is in gettingEvents?

Comment: well, first you would have to make the ajax call synchronous, if you wanted to send synchronous ajax calls. But, that's a bad idea, don't do that. You should instead make this work asynchronously by either sending them all in parallel and then dealing with the results in the original order, or by sending them one after the other (which means not looping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they really are synchronous, then simply **not using setTimeout** will do the job.

```
$.each(matchIds, function(key,val){
    gettingEvents(key, val,userID);
});
```

This is, however, a terrible approach that will tie up the JS event loop while all the requests run. Use asynchronous requests instead. Iterate inside the success handler instead of in an `each` loop.

```
var match_id_keys = Object.keys(matchIds);
var i = 0;
get_next();

function get_next() {
    if (!match_id_keys[i]) {
        return;
    }
    var key = match_id_keys[i];
    var val = matchIds[key];
    $.ajax( ... ).done(function () {
        // Do stuff with data
        i++;
        get_next();
    });
}
```

In 2020, we now have [decent browser support for `async` and `await`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_await) which are tools for managing promises, so this can be written as a simpler loop:

async function get_all_ids(matchIds) {
const entries = Object.entries(matchIds);
for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
const [key, val] = entries[i];
const data = await $.ajax(...);
// Do stuff with data
}
}

Comment: I've tried, it didn't seem to work : \ I've even tried to set a return value but it didn't help

Comment: @Mapisto — There isn't enough code in your question to tell *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: for the second approach: +1